# How to search in hash column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

How to search in hash column on `Postgresql` ?

### product model

```
serialize :properties, Hash
```

### product migration

```
add_column :products, :properties, :text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use sql `LIKE` operation to search in the text column.

You can switch to postgresql that has native support of hstore columns or migrate to Rails 5 that support json type column. [Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#hstore)

Comment: rails return 'PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown'

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 Product.where("properties->>'foo' = 'bar'")
```

Comment: rails return 'PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown'